# xfce-mixer does not work as expected

Tags: xfce

I am using ubuntu 12.04 and I chagne to xfce 4.6.

Then I found that I can get no voice when I play a mp3 using the audacious or watch some video in youtube.

And I found the xfce-mixer which is used to control the voice in xfce.

After some setting I can listen the song but with a very noise background-voice.

Normally, a song will conatain the singer's voice and the background music. Now the background-music is higher than the singer's voice.

This is my setting of mixer:

[image]

As you can see, there are two scroll bars.

After some test,I found that the left control the singer's voice, and the right control the background-music.

However when I scroll over the `mixer track in the lower-right of my desktop using the mouse scroller, the singer's voice will get  synchronized with the background-music:

[image]

Do I miss anything?

Comment: Could you please clarify the question, as it is not very clear?

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess.  Maybe you have a a surround sound card, like 5.1 surround, and the mixer is not controlling all the volumes.  It's happened to me.  On the mixer, click on where it says "Sound Card: Playback: Builtin etc." and see if another sound card is offered.
   If that not work, try click on "Select Control" and see if you can add controls for channels that you are missing.